# Schrodinger equation for an atom

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation

Does schrodinger equation describes only electrons and subatomic particles or also the atoms?

Comment: Hint: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_atom

Comment: Are you asking if a whole atom also obeys the Schrodinger equation?

Comment: Are you asking about an atom modelled as a point particle?

Comment: Yes does atom has known position and momentum? Also when we refer to the momentum of a macroscopic object we dont refer heisenberg priciple but isnt actually heisenberg principle also holds for macroscopic objects?

Answer (score 1):

No, it generalizes to larger particles as well.

Answer (score 0):

The Schrodinger equation describes non-relativistic particles with no reference to spin. As such, it has wide application beyond electrons and other subatomic particles.